Is there a way to narrow down the type properly?
Can anyone recommend please how to narrow down the type within the validateField function?
type TStringValidator = (v: string) => void;
type TNumberValidator = (v: number) => void;

type TFields = 'inn' | 'amount';

interface IValidators {
  inn: TStringValidator[];
  amount: TNumberValidator[];
}

const handleString: TStringValidator = (value: string) => {};
const handleNumber: TNumberValidator = (value: number) => {};

const validators = {
  inn: [handleString],
  amount: [handleNumber],
} satisfies IValidators;

function validateField(field: TFields, value: string | number) {
  const fieldValidators = validators[field];

  for (const validator of fieldValidators) {
    // Problem is here
    const result = validator(value);
  }

  return;
}

Link to the TS playground.
Expect validator(value) call not to throw TS error:
Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2345)
(parameter) value: string | number

It is clear that TS compiler can't clearly get the type for the dynamic validator based on a field value.
Maybe some validateField refactoring can help.

To avoid the never type,  you can define a set of all authorized type in validator
type AllowedTypes = string & number;

then in the call of the generic validator function just cast the variable as allowed type
const result = validator(value as AllowedTypes);

full sample
type TStringValidator = (v: string) => void;
type TNumberValidator = (v: number) => void;

type TFields = 'inn' | 'amount';
type AllowedTypes = string & number;

interface IValidators {
  inn: TStringValidator[];
  amount: TNumberValidator[];
}

const handleString: TStringValidator = (value: string) => {};
const handleNumber: TNumberValidator = (value: number) => {};

const validators = {
  inn: [handleString],
  amount: [handleNumber],
}
satisfies IValidators;

function validateField(field: TFields, value: string | number) {
  const fieldValidators: (TNumberValidator | TStringValidator)[] = validators[field];

  for (const validator of fieldValidators) {
    const result = validator(value as AllowedTypes);
  }

  return;


I think the problem here is that your value is string or number and TS is not aware of the exact type validator inside the loop (either TStringValidator or TNumberValidator). Now your stucture is a bit uncomfortable in my opinion but you can still make it work like this:
function validateField(field: TFields, value: string | number) {
  const fieldValidators = validators[field];

  Object.keys(validators).forEach(key => {
    if (key === 'inn' && typeof value === 'string') {
      const result = validators[key][0](value)
    }
  })

  return;
}

You can always improve the code above but you get the point.

Hey! Thanks for the answer :)
First, I believe there's a type here in your response:
// validators -> fieldValidators

Object.keys(fieldValidators).forEach(key => {
    if (key === 'inn' && typeof value === 'string') {
      const result = validators[key][0](value)
    }
  })

That would work for sure, but will require comparing all the keys and types for the fieldValidators dictionary. Wich I wanted to get rid of, but to make dynamic.
